# How to join three tables in Apache Derby Database?

Tags: java, sql, derby

**Question:**

What syntax do I need to use to simply join three tables using Apache Derby?

**What I have tried:**

I am converting a Java application from SQLite to Apache Derby.
In SQLite, the following SQL syntax works fine.

```
sql.append("SELECT MatterDataset.id,  ");
//Removed rest of selection items for readability and to focus the inquiry

sql.append(" FROM MatterDataset, DocumentClassification, PrivilegeLog  " ) ; //<--PROBLEM LINE
sql.append("  ON MatterDataset.matterid = DocumentClassification.matterid  " ) ;
sql.append("   AND MatterDataset.matterid = PrivilegeLog.matterid   " ) ;
sql.append("   AND MatterDataset.id = DocumentClassification.documentid   " ) ;
sql.append("   AND MatterDataset.id = PrivilegeLog.documentparentid    " ) ;
sql.append(" WHERE    " ) ;
sql.append("  Matterdataset.matterid = ? " ) ; //Prepared statement
sql.append("  AND Matterdataset.isdeleted = 0  " ) ;
```

The line causing problems with the conversion to Apache Derby is:

```
sql.append(" FROM MatterDataset, DocumentClassification, PrivilegeLog  " ) ;
```

I have tried several variations and all raise syntax errors with Java Derby (via the ij tool).

1) SYNTAX ERROR at the ',' but this syntax works with only two tables

```
sql.append(" FROM MatterDataset JOIN DocumentClassification, PrivilegeLog  " ) ;
```

2) Direct as above and SYNTAX ERROR at the ","

```
sql.append(" FROM MatterDataset, DocumentClassification, PrivilegeLog  " ) ; //
```

3) SYNTAX ERROR at the "AND"

```
sql.append(" FROM MatterDataset JOIN DocumentClassification AND PrivilegeLog  " ) ; //
```

I am not sure what else to try (after performing a web search for similar issues with SQL in general). Is there a way to do this simply in Apache Derby?

**Environment Setup:**

Java 7
Apache Derby 10.9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join tables simply with `,`

```
sql.append("SELECT MatterDataset.id  ");
//Removed rest of selection items for readability and to focus the inquiry

sql.append(" FROM MatterDataset, DocumentClassification, PrivilegeLog  " ) ; //<--NOT A PROBLEM LINE
sql.append(" WHERE    " ) ;
sql.append("   MatterDataset.id = DocumentClassification.matterid  " ) ;
sql.append("   AND MatterDataset.id = PrivilegeLog.matterid   " ) ;
sql.append("   AND DocumentClassification.id = PrivilegeLog.documentparentid    " ) ;
sql.append("   AND Matterdataset.id = ? " ) ; //Prepared statement
sql.append("   AND Matterdataset.isdeleted = 0  " ) ;
```

The Derby database also could be [optimized for performance](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/tuning/perf44.html#Joins+and+Performance).

Comment: I am not following your answer. The comma-JOIN method results in a syntax error (specifically at the ',') when used with Apache Derby. Apache Derby ij reports: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "," at line 1, column 71.

Comment: column 71? why no column 24? If you read the link there's sample queries with joins.

Comment: I see a link is now added. Thank you for putting the link in.

Comment: @SaB you should accept this answer as solution instead of copying it to your own.

Comment: I apologize @nikpon. I deleted the response below. I only meant to clarify the final solution in the code. I really meant no offense. The second copy and comments was deleted this afternoon. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you were trying to mix two different styles of join syntax.

Using ON syntax to specify the join conditions is a different style than using WHERE
syntax.

When you use ON syntax, your SELECT statement should look like:

SELECT columns FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON t1-t2 join conditions JOIN T3 ON ...

But when you use a comma separated table list, you don't use ON clauses, you just lump all the join conditions into the WHERE clause.

So don't mix the two styles, just use one or the other.

By the way, the older style that you chose is great for INNER join, but can't be used for OUTER join, so it's generally the need to specify an OUTER join that causes programmers to switch to the ON clause style.

But you can use ON clause for INNER joins too, just don't give a comma-separated table list.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. I spent most of today working with variations of this to see how the differences in syntax affect the outcomes.